# Actionscript - Dynamically assigning imported objects

Tags: object, actionscript, assign

Take this simplified code

```
import assets.panels.About1;
import assets.panels.About2;
import assets.panels.About3;

private var _panel:*;

_panel = new About1();
```

It is possible to define `About1` as a variable, so I can set something like

```
var aboutPanel = 'About3';
```

So code executed would be

```
_panel = new About3();
```

Comment: Could you explain more your problem ?

Comment: I have a large number of panels, based on user selection I need to open the correct panel. Currently I have a giant if statement for each condition, where I assign the required panel to the panel object. If instead of this I could just say _panel = new MYPANELVARIABLE(); this would be far neater with less code.

Comment: I abandoned "fash.utils.getDefinitionByName" solution because you must initiate every import to stop the compiler removing them, so this solution actually swaps one blob of code for another in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can use [`flash.utils.getDefinitionByName`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName()) like this :

```
var class_name:String = 'MyClass';

var my_class:Class = flash.utils.getDefinitionByName(class_name) as Class;

trace(my_class);    // gives : [class MyClass]  

var obj = new my_class();
addChild(obj);  

trace(obj);         // gives : [object MyClass]
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks, that look like the solution.